# How to remove keychain store with LockBox

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I'm testing my in-app purchases (non-consumable) and using [LockBox](https://github.com/granoff/Lockbox) to store the productID's for purchased items.  However I can't seem to figure out how to delete/remove/reset the items once they're store using LockBox.  I thought deleting the app from my device would do the trick, but the keychains still exist.  I tried using the demo project and it to can retrieve (fetch) a string value after deleting the app.  Not sure if this is intended functionality, so thought I'd ask here if anyone knows a way to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looked into the LockBox code and found the key will be deleted if you the the value to nil:

```
    BOOL result = [Lockbox setString:nil forKey:myKeyString];
```

Couldn't be easier!

Comment: But how does it work if I don't know the key name and I just want to delete all keys?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to remove all keys in keychain.